# Embedding python interpreter into static library

Tags: c++, static-libraries, cpython

I have a function that I want to put into a static library:

`run_me.h`:

```cpp
void run_me();
```

`run_me.cpp`:

```cpp
namespace {
std::mutex python_mutex;
struct PythonScopedLock {
    PythonScopedLock() : _lock(python_mutex) {
        PyEval_AcquireLock();
    }

    ~PythonScopedLock() {
        PyEval_ReleaseLock();
    }

private:
    std::lock_guard<decltype(python_mutex)> _lock;
};

struct PythonInterpreter {
    PythonInterpreter() {
        Py_InitializeEx(0);
        PyEval_InitThreads();
        PyEval_ReleaseLock();
    }

    ~PythonInterpreter() {
        PyEval_AcquireLock();
        Py_Finalize();
    }
};
const PythonInterpreter python_interpreter;
} //namespace

void run_me()
{
    PythonScopedLock lock;
    // import python module and call some python code
}
```

Next, in the following executable, I get a crash almost instantly on `PyObject_Malloc`.

```cpp
#include <tbb/tbb.h>
#include "run_me.h"
int main(){
    using namespace tbb;
    parallel_for(blocked_range<size_t>(0, 1234, 1), [&](const blocked_range<size_t>& r) {
        for (auto it = r.begin(); it != r.end(); ++it) {
            run_me();
        }
    });    
}
```

I checked the threads with gdb and they are nicely waiting for lock to be unlocked, but one of them crashes:

```
  1    Thread 0x7ffff7fdb900 (LWP 21474) "tests" 0x00007ffff69374ed in __lll_lock_wait () from /lib64/libpthread.so.0
  2    Thread 0x7fffef349700 (LWP 21483) "tests" 0x00007ffff69374ed in __lll_lock_wait () from /lib64/libpthread.so.0
  3    Thread 0x7fffeef48700 (LWP 21484) "tests" 0x00007ffff69374ed in __lll_lock_wait () from /lib64/libpthread.so.0
* 4    Thread 0x7fffeeb47700 (LWP 21485) "tests" PyObject_Malloc (nbytes=41) at Objects/obmalloc.c:831
  5    Thread 0x7fffee746700 (LWP 21486) "tests" 0x00007ffff69374ed in __lll_lock_wait () from /lib64/libpthread.so.0
  6    Thread 0x7fffedf44700 (LWP 21488) "tests" 0x00007ffff69374ed in __lll_lock_wait () from /lib64/libpthread.so.0
  7    Thread 0x7fffee345700 (LWP 21487) "tests" 0x00007ffff69374ed in __lll_lock_wait () from /lib64/libpthread.so.0
```

Situation changes when I move out `PythonScopedLock` from the body of `run_me` and put it into lambda body. This runs just fine:

```cpp
#include <tbb/tbb.h>
#include "run_me.h"

namespace {
std::mutex python_mutex;
struct PythonScopedLock {
    PythonScopedLock() : _lock(python_mutex) {
        PyEval_AcquireLock();
    }

    ~PythonScopedLock() {
        PyEval_ReleaseLock();
    }

private:
    std::lock_guard<decltype(python_mutex)> _lock;
};
} // namespace 

int main(){
    using namespace tbb;
    parallel_for(blocked_range<size_t>(0, 1234, 1), [&](const blocked_range<size_t>& r) {
        for (auto it = r.begin(); it != r.end(); ++it) {
            PythonScopedLock lock;
            run_me();
        }
    });
}
```

I have few questions:

1. <s>What is the difference, in this context, between heaving a lock inside of the lambda or a body of the function? To me it's the same, I just want to hide that lock inside of body of the function.</s>
2. <s>What are possible causes of the crash?</s>
3. What are other problems besides static initialisation fiasco, that I can encounter during interpreter initialisation through a variable in anon namespace through `const PythonInterpreter python_interpreter;`?

**EDIT**

After a bit of debugging I noticed when `lock` is inside of `run_me` definition, in the static library, `PyGILState_GetThisThreadState` returns `NULL`. When `lock` is outside, in the main thread then it returns same pointer as `_PyThreadState_Current`. That kind of answers question number 1. and 2.

Question 3. still remains open.